# Copy/move EBS volume from one Region to another

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, migration, amazon-ebs

**Background of our setup:**
We've hosted our web-based application in Amazon EC2 US East (Virginia) Region. Our instance is based on Linux distribution (CentOS) and AMI is S3-backed.  1 EBS volume (400 GB size) is attached to this instance.

**Question:**
We've planned to migrate our deployment to US West (N. California) Region.  From AWS doc, I understood that for moving AMI, there is a command-line tool available - [ec2-migrate-bundle](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-ami-migrate-bundle.html).  But for moving EBS volume across Region, currently there is no tool available.

I'm looking for easiest and/or fastest way of copying/moving EBS volume from one Region to another.  Also, are there any hidden risks involved during and/or after the migration?

Experts ideas/suggestions/recommendations on this are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon recently announced [**EBS Snapshot Copy**](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/12/17/announcing-ebs-snapshot-copy/) which enables to copy EBS snapshots across AWS regions, thus making it easier to leverage multiple AWS regions and accelerate geographical expansion, data center migration and disaster recovery.

- [Announcing EBS Snapshot Copy, a Step towards Easier Data Center Migration and Disaster Recovery](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/12/17/announcing-ebs-snapshot-copy/)
- [Copying an Amazon EBS Snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-copy-snapshot.html)

**NOTE:** Amazon EC2 is also planning to launch *Amazon Machine Image (AMI) Copy* as a follow-up to this feature, which will enable to copy both public and custom-created AMIs across regions.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this post](http://blog.taggesell.de/index.php?/archives/85-Amazon-EC2-How-to-migrate-an-EBS-backed-image-from-US-to-EU-or-wherever.html) they explain how to do it.
BTW the use cpipe to copy the content across the network, that means 400Gb over the wire :S

Comment: Thanks for that useful link. In that post, there is a command `cpipe -vt -b 1024 < /dev/sdf | netcat -q 1 ec2-hostname 9999`.  But in my CentOS 5.2, I don't find the option `-q` in `netcat` command.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Gnanam I couldn't find that option on my nc... I don't know for what it is, also the man documentation do not say anything :S.
I think you can try without it to see what happens

Comment: From mine, "-q after EOF on stdin, wait the specified number of seconds and then quit. If seconds is negative, wait forever.".  You're probably OK without it, but I suppose it might be useful if there was some lag in pulling the data off the disk.